# iOS - Application debugging on .ipa file

Tags: ios, xcode, debugging, ipa

Is there a way to debug a .ipa file after archiving?

I have a bug that I am running into when I archive to .ipa file that doesn't show up in xcode when I am running tests.

Thanks,

Comment: When you test your app using Xcode, are you just using the simulator for testing, or are you testing on real devices as well?

Comment: On a real device mostly, but sometimes simulator.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Presumably your testing is done with a Debug build, whereas your archive is a Release build? You can check this if you select 'Edit Scheme' from the schemes drop down in Xcode.

To test the archive build, you can change your "Run" setting to use a release build rather than debug - click on Run in the left hand panel from the Edit Scheme screen and then the Info tab and change the Build Configuration to Release.

Don't forget to turn it back to Debug once you have finished.

The thing is - it's pretty rare to find issues like this, could you perhaps explain more about what your problem actually is?

Comment: Can I simulate ipad app .ipa file in xcode and do all debugging activities in Xcode itself?